# NavEE selected_class="on" becomes class="yes" - possible to solve w/o updating styling?

Tags: templates, parsing, navee, 2.9

I assume due to some bug in the parser,

```
{exp:navee:nav nav_title="header" selected_class="on"}
```

Outputs

```
<ul>
    <li class="yes"><a href="/foo">Foo</a></li>
    <li><a href="/bar">Bar</a></li>
    <li><a href="/baz">Baz</a></li>
</ul>
```

While I am able to change the styles, it would be highly preferable to overcome this issue, as the navigation is being retrofitted.

Has anyone else hit a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a bit of a poke around in EE core, and found the likely culprit. (`system/libraries/Template.php:1690`, in `fetch_param()`)

```
// Making yes/no tag parameters consistent.  No "y/n" or "on/off".
switch($this->tagparams[$which])
{
  case 'y'  :
  case 'on' :
    return 'yes';
  break;
  case 'n'  :
  case 'off'  :
    return 'no';
  break;
  default   :
    return $this->tagparams[$which];
  break;
}
```

It would seem that the system translates all instances of y, on, n, and off into different values with no option to disable this functionality for modules using the function.

Frankly, I'm disappointed.

For now, I'd presume this impossible to fix without modifying core files.